# zlib compress2() taking 30s to compress a buffer of size 1.5GB. It seems compress2() is taking too much time, or is it okay?

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

Here is the code:
buffer is the original 1.5GB buffer to be compressed.

```
        char* buffer = new char[originalBufferSize];

        long unsigned int compressedSize = 0;
        compressedSize = compressBound(originalBufferSize);
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        
        unsigned char * pData = new unsigned char[compressedSize];
        int nResult = compress2((Bytef*)(pData), &compressedSize, (const Bytef*)buffer, originalBufferSize, 1);
    
        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(stop - start);

        std::cout << "\nTime taken by to compress: "<< duration.count() << " seconds" << endl;
        resultBuffer = buffer;
```

Comment: Try zlib-ng, it should increase the deflation speed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't think that this depends on what machine you're using?

As it happens, using the default compression setting (6) on my Apple M1 Max processor, it takes 33 seconds. With level 1 compression, it takes 10 seconds. On my Raspberry Pi 3B+, at level 6, it took almost five minutes. At level 1 it took two minutes.